# Iterate over two strings and count repeated letters

Tags: string, python-3.x, dictionary

I am accepting two strings through command line.

What I want is,

- The first string wins if it contains more z’s than the second string.
- If they have the same number 
   of z’s, then the string with the most y’s wins.
- If they have the same number of y’s, then the number of x’s
  determines the winner, etc.
- If they contain the same number of z’s, y’s .... a’s, then it’s a tie
  and there is no winner.

What I had planned to do was,

create a dictionary with all alphabets and assign incrementing values like,

```
alphabets = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3, ... ,y=25, z=26)
```

and mulptiple its values by the number of times the letter repeated.

```
For example, python myprogram.py zzza zzza 
string1: zzza and string2: zzza 
In string1, Z is repeated 3 times and a is repeated once.
In string2, Z is repeated 2 times, b and a is repeated once.
So, (26*3) + (2*1) and (26*2) + (2*1) + (1*1)
```

string with maximum number would win. But, it does not give correct answer always.
(string1: zzza and string2: zyyx condition fails)

```
word1_count = {}
word2_count = {}

class FindWinner:
def __init__(self, word1, word2):
    self.word1 = word1
    self.word2 = word2

def check_conditions(self):

    special_chars = set('[~!@#$%^&*.-()_+{}":;01234567989\']+$')

# check conditions 
    if special_chars.intersection(self.word1) or 
         special_chars.intersection(self.word2) or \
        (len(self.word1) != len(self.word2) or ('no' in self.word1)
        or ('no' in self.word2)) or (self.word1 == self.word2):

       print('Invalid string.')

    else:
        print("String is valid")

        for w1 in list(self.word1):
            if w1 not in word1_count:
                word1_count[w1] = 1
            else:
                word1_count[w1] += 1

        for w2 in list(self.word2):
                if w2 not in word2_count:
                    word2_count[w2] = 1
                else:
                    word2_count[w2] += 1

        # print(word1_count, word2_count)

    merged_data = [[k, word1_count.get(k, 0), word2_count.get(k, 0)] for k in word1_count.keys() | word2_count.keys()]

    print(merged_data)


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("word1", help="First word")
    parser.add_argument("word2", help="Second word")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    c1 = FindWinner(args.word1, args.word2)
    c1.check_conditions()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Input:
`python myprogramm.py qwwweq asdnnn`

Output:

`String is valid
{'e': 1, 'q': 2, 'w': 3} {'d': 1, 'a': 1, 'n': 3, 's': 1} # merged_data`

What should be the approach?
Thanks

Comment: hey @batMan, I am not sure what are you talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach doesn't work because twenty-six `a` characters gives the same score as one `z` character; 26 * 1 == 1 * 26.

You instead should treat this as a *sorting problem*, where you are sorting by the letter counts. Count the letters in each word, then take the counts in reverse alphabetical order as a tuple and have Python pick the winner with `max()`. Python sequences are compared lexicographically; a list with `[3, 2]` is sorted *after* `[3, 1]` because the second digit is larger in the first; `max()` would pick it over the second.

Counting is trivially done with a [`collections.Counter()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
from string import ascii_lowercase

def letter_counts(word):
    counts = Counter(word)
    return [counts.get(l, 0) for l in reversed(ascii_lowercase)]

lcounts1 = letter_counts(word1)
lcounts2 = letter_counts(word2)
if lcounts1 == lcounts2:
    # tie
    print('No winner')
else:
    _, winner = max((lcounts1, word1), (lcounts2, word2))
    print(winner)
```

`letter_counts()` produces a list of 26 integers, each a count for the letters `z` through to `a`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without a dictionary.
Creating a dictionary as part of pre-processing is an additional overhead.
We can check the count of each letter starting from `(z..a)` one by one in both the strings. If there is a max we can break the loop and declare the winner. This is much efficient than using dictionaries for solving this problem.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

str1="hellozzzz"
str2="yellozzzz"
winner=""

for ele in reversed(ascii_lowercase):
    diff=str1.count(ele)-str2.count(ele)
    if(diff>0):
        winner=str1
        break
    elif (diff<0):
        winner=str2
        break

print winner if(winner) else "It's a tie"
```

Comment: Thanks batMan.
I checked for various strings and program failed for few cases.
input:
str1="yellozzzzzz"
str2="hellozzzzzz"
output:
hellozzzzzz is winner

As per condition, yellozzzzzz should be the winner

Comment: Sorry !! a mistake. If you check in my first for loop where I'm setting up dictionary for str1, I've mentioned  d[l]=0 in else case. I've corrected it do d[l]=1, updated the answer and it's working fine.

Comment: This does exactly the same thing my answer does, only without a Counter object and `max()`.

Comment: I would say `this is more efficient` as it doesn't preprocesses counts for all letters and `stops` as soon as the condition is satisfied without needing to check and store count for further letters :)

Comment: @batman: no, the counting is already done, and is O(K) where K is the length of the inputs. Only collating the counts into a list is short-circuited here. At most 26 such numbers are looked up, so there is very little opportunity for that to be made faster. The C code doing the comparisons in my answer are probably still going to beat even a comparison where on strings where one string has more z characters than the other.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Sorry, I've realised I didn't update my answer before posting my comment. That's where the confusion started. I've updated it now. My point is we don't need a dictionary to solve this problem, it's an additional overhead. If you compare two programs you'll see this is 26-30 times faster in best case i.e when there is a difference of just z chars; and 2-3 times faster in worst case i.e when both the strings are same. You can check it on your local using timeit. [Check](https://repl.it/LuN0/2) for reference

Comment: For the short example it could indeed be fast enough, but take into account that `str.count()` does a full string scan, so for the worst-case scenario you make 26 as many full scans as using a Counter would.